# sql SELECT query for 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 3 tables:
1. `products(product_id,name)`
2. `orders(id,order_id,product_id)`
3. `factors(id,order_id,date)`

I want to retrieve product names(`products.name`) where have similar `order_id` on a  `date` in two last tables. 
I use this query for this purpose:

```
select products.name
    from products

    WHERE products.product_id ~IN 
    (
    SELECT distinct orders.product_id FROM orders WHERE
    order_id IN (select order_id FROM factors WHERE 
    factors.datex ='2017-04-29') GROUP BY product_id
    )
```

but no result. where is my mistake? how can I resolve that? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be fine.  I am rewriting it to make a few changes to the structure, but not the logic (this makes it easier for me to understand the query):

```
select p.name
from products p
where p.product_id in (select o.product_id
                       from orders o
                       where o.order_id in (select f.order_id
                                            from factors f
                                            where f.datex = '2017-04-29'
                                           ) 
                      ) ;
```

Notes on the changes:

- When using multiple tables in a query, *always* qualify the column names.
- Use table aliases.  They make queries easier to write and to read.
- `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` are unnecessary in `IN` subqueries.  The logic of `IN` already handles (i.e. ignores) duplicates.  And by explicitly including the operations, you run the risk of a less efficient query plan.

Why might your query not work?

- `factors.datex` has a time component.  If so, then this will work `date(f.datex) = '2017-04-29'`.
- There are no factors on that date.
- There are no orders that match factors on that date.
- There are no products in the orders that match the factors on that date.

Comment: thanks for your nice answer. I find my mistake and my products ID's inserts from an old ID's that incorrect. but mine and your query is TRUE...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have another mistake. can u help me there plzz: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716904/sql-select-values-on-continuous-period-of-time [/link]

Answer (score 1):

In factors table column name is date so it should be -

```
 factors.date ='2017-04-29'
```

You have written -

```
factors.datex ='2017-04-29'
```

Comment: this may be a typo somewhere on the part of the question poster, but there is a clear disparity that they claim to have the column `date` but the SQL is using the column name `datex`